# Rendering components based on parameter values in data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am loading data that was created using a "To-Do List" feature and the users order the list in which ever way they want. The data returned isn't in the order that the user saved. The data does include a data parameter with the index of the order.

```js
const userGoals = {
  "Alen": {
    order: 2,
    goals: ["Learn JavaScript.", "Learn VueJS.", "Learn React."]
  },
  "Cole": {
    order: 1,
    goals: ["Learn JavaScript.", "Learn to paint.", "Learn Karate."]
  },
  "Lucas": {
    order: 0,
    goals: ["Learn to draw.", "Build a canoe.", "Learn to paint."]
  }
}

Vue.component('goal-list', {
  props: {
    users: Object
  },
  template: `
 <div>
  <ol v-for="(user, index) in users">
   <strong>{{ user.order }} {{ index }}</strong>
   <li v-for="goal in user.goals"> {{ goal }}</li>
  </ol>
 </div>
 `
});

var list = new Vue({
  el: '#userList',
  data: {
    users: userGoals
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Goals</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Goals</h1>

  <div id="userList">
    <goal-list :users="users"></goal-list>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Component render order should be

1. Lucas
2. Cole
3. Alen

based on the order parameter in each user object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this thanks to [**Ohgodwhy!**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206267/ohgodwhy)

I still used a computed property since I didn't need to sort the data after render again and from what I understand Methods are better for things like click events.

Since I had objects inside objects I had to restructure the data a bit to get sort to work.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/alensubasic/ghnpdkev/)

```js
const userGoals = {
  "Alen": {
    order: 1,
    goals: ["Learn JavaScript.", "Learn VueJS.", "Learn React."]
  },
  "Lucas": {
    order: 2,
    goals: ["Learn to draw.", "Build a canoe.", "Paint a painting."]
  },
  "Cole": {
    order: 3,
    goals: ["Learn JavaScript.", "Learn to paint.", "Learn Karate."]
  },
  "Tahir": {
    order: 0,
    goals: ["Lift something heavy.", "Lift something even heavier!", "Relax."]
  }
}

Vue.component('goal-list', {
  props: {
    users: Object
  },
  template: `
 <div>
  <ol v-for="(user, index) in sortedUsers">
   <strong>{{ user.order }} {{ user.key }}</strong>
   <li v-for="goal in user.goals"> {{ goal }}</li>
  </ol>
 </div>
 `,
  computed: {
    sortedUsers() {
      return Object.keys(this.users)
        .map(i => {
          this.$set(this.users[i], 'key', i)
          return this.users[i]
        }).sort((a, b) => {
          return a.order > b.order ? 1 : (a.order < b.order ? -1 : 0)
        });
    }
  }
});

var list = new Vue({
  el: '#userList',
  data() {
    return {
      users: userGoals
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Goals</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Goals</h1>

  <div id="userList">
    <goal-list :users="users"></goal-list>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <!-- Vue.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom JavaScript -->
  <script src="/script.js"></script>"
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` on the `order` property of your users and return that from a computed getter:

```
computed: {
  sortedUsers: {
    get: function() {
      return this.users.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.order > b.order ? 1 : (a.order < b.order ? -1 : 0)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Then update your component to use this getter instead of your pure data object.

Comment: This help me look in the right direction and I ended up finding a solution.